# Regex to match the specified word exactly, or the word with a space, or the word preceded by a specific letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a word `temp` and I would like a regex to match `temp` exactly, or `temp` preceded by an arbitrary string followed by either a space or the letter `g` (i.e. `blahblah temp` or `blahblahgtemp`). I thought something like `[^g ]temp$` would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[ g])temp$
```

To break it out:

```
(?<=               # Match after (positive lookbehind)
  [ g]             # either space or 'g'
)                  # 
temp               # 'temp' literally
$                  # followed by nothing (end of string).
```